# Construction of a triangle with given angle bisectors

Tags: euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

given three distinct lines $g,h,l$ meeting in one point $P$. I want to construct a triangle with vertices on $g,h,l$ such that those lines $g,h,l$ become its angle bisectors.

In general, if we consider a triangle $\Delta(ABC)$ with angles $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ whose angle bisectors meet at a point $P$, then I recognized the following relations between the angles:

$$\angle (APB)=\frac{1}{2}(\pi+\gamma), \angle (BPC)=\frac{1}{2}(\pi+\alpha), \angle (CPA)=\frac{1}{2}(\pi+\beta).$$

Now suppose we choose points $C,C'\in g$ on different sides of $g$ with respect to $P$ and let $Q\in l,R\in h$ such that $C'$ lies in the interior of the angle $\angle (QPR)$. I started the construction as follows:

- Construct the angle $\angle (QPR)-\pi/2$ on one side of $g$ at the point C. Then we get a intersection point $A$ with the ray $\overrightarrow{PQ}$.
- Construct the angle $\angle (QPR)-\pi/2$ on the other side of $g$ at the point C. Then we get a intersection point $B$ with the ray $\overrightarrow{PR}$.
- Now connect the points $A,B$

But now I'm worried about the angles at $A,B$. I do not know if the angles have the right size and the lines $l,h$ through $A,B$ are indeed angle bisectors? Maybe my construction is wrong. Do you know how to do it right?

Best wishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the angles 
between the lines be $\phi$, $\psi$ and $\omega$,
$\phi+\psi+\omega=2\pi$.
Intersection point $P$ 
is a center of the inscribed circle,
so let's draw a circle with arbitrary radius, e.g. $r=1$:

[image]

Here we have a system of equations:
\begin{align}
\tfrac12\alpha+\tfrac12\gamma&=\pi-\phi
\\
\tfrac12\beta+\tfrac12\gamma&=\pi-\psi
\\
\tfrac12\alpha+\tfrac12\beta&=\pi-\omega
\end{align}

which results in
\begin{align}
\alpha &= \pi-\omega-\phi+\psi
\\
\beta &= \pi-\phi-\psi+\omega
\\
\gamma &= \pi-\psi-\omega+\phi
\end{align}

Now, 
$|AP|=r/\sin\tfrac\alpha2$,
$|BP|=r/\sin\tfrac\beta2$,
$|CP|=r/\sin\tfrac\gamma2$.