# How is a vertex of a triangle moving while another vertex is moving on its angle bisector?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

While trying to solve [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356043/construction-of-a-triangle-with-given-angle-bisectors) the following conjecture came to my mind. Based on the statement conjectured I could solve the problem mentioned. I am unable to verify the statement that I found interesting in itself. Help needed.

**The conjecture**

Consider the the concurrent distinct lines $\color{blue}{a}$ and $\color{blue}{b}$, the angle bisectors of the triangle $A,B,C$ at $A$ and $B$ respectively. The inscribed circle $\color{blue}{i}$ is given now.

Move the point $A$ on the line $\color{blue}{a}$ and construct $B'$ and $C'$ such that circle $\color{blue}{i}$ remains the inscribed circle and the lines $\color{blue}{a}$ and $\color{blue}{b}$ remain the angle bisectors as before.

The third vertex $C'$ moves on a circle denoted by $\color{red}{?}$. (The center of $\color{red}{?}$ coincides with the center of $\color{blue}{i}$.)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Let $O$ be the center of the incircle, and say that lines $\overleftrightarrow{OA}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{OB}$ make an angle of size $\varphi$. Let $P$, $P^\prime$, and $Q$ be the points of tangency of $\triangle ABC$ with the incircle, as shown; writing $\theta := \angle AOP = \angle AOQ$, and noting that $P^\prime$ is the reflection of $P$ in $\overleftrightarrow{OB}$, we see that
$$\angle AOP^\prime = \angle AOP + 2\angle BOP = \theta + 2(\varphi - \theta) = 2\varphi - \theta$$

Therefore, $\angle QOP^\prime$ (the long way around) is given by
$$\angle QOP^\prime = \angle QOA + \angle AOP^\prime = \theta + (2\varphi - \theta) = 2\varphi$$
which is a constant in this scenario. Thus, $\square OP^\prime C Q$ has a constant shape as $A$ moves, and we have easily that $|\overline{OC}| = r\operatorname{sec}\varphi$, where $r$ is the radius of the circle.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the bisectors $a$ and $b$ intersect at $I$, and the angle between them is $\alpha$. If you were to draw heights from $I$ then after a bit of angle chasing and a touch of trigonometry you will find that $$|CI| = \frac{r_i}{\cos\alpha}$$ where $r_i$ is the radius of the small circle.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$